# How do I declare a JavaScript Global variable for a function, inside itself?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, global-variables

I have some JavaScript code like this:

```js
var account_name;
fetch('[URL]')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((out) => {
    account_name = out.account_name;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
                
console.log(account_name);
account_name_field.innerHTML = account_name;
```

But when I run it, the console says:

```
User.html:192 Uncaught ReferenceError: account_name is not defined
at update_from_config (User.html:194)
at onload (User.html:76)
```

I've tried multiple methods to declare a global variable, but none of them seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't. Put all the functionality inside the `.then` callback instead

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really know what .then did. I'll make sure to try this.